# It is faraway / far away (from X) to Y

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, predicate

> It is **faraway / far away** (from X) to Y

Here, to say *how far* it is from one place to another, should we use the *adjective* **faraway** or the *adverb* **far away**?

Answer (score 1):

Adverbial use:

How **far away** is your destination?
How far is it from X to Y?

Adjective:

I dream of **faraway** places.
He sat at the **far** end of the row.

https://wordtype.org/of/far
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/far

Answer (score 0):

To ask how far it is we say, "How far is it from X to Y?" or "How far is Y from X?"

To ask if they are far apart we say, "Are X and Y far apart?" or "Is it far from X to Y?"

We say a place is "a long way from here", or "a long way away from here".

If it *isn't* a long way, we say "it's not far from here". And we might ask, "Is it far from here?" But, oddly, in the UK "It's far from here" sounds a little as if it comes from a fairy tale.

If it is a long way away we generally describe a place as distant ("a distant town", "distant parts of the world"). Less prosaically we might call it far-off ("a far-off town", "far-off places".)

More romantically or whimsically, we might call it "a faraway town". We might "dream of visiting faraway places." (Here is [The Magic Faraway Tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree))

Comment: Quaint? Far from here? Not the right word there. If you live in a huge country like the US, we say that all the time: Oh, x? It's far from here. About fifty miles.

Comment: "far from here" is a stock phrase in American English. According to Ngram, "far from here" is far more common than "long way from here."

Comment: @Lambie: Thanks. Didn't know that. It's curious that in the UK _is it far from here_ and _it's not far from here_ are used so often, yet '_it is far from here_' seems almost to belong in a fairy tale.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: Thank you. I hadn't realised it was a pondian thing.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian Neither did I recognize the pondian issue until I read your answer. I have tried  to restrict my answers **explicitly** to American English. I needed subtitles ro watch “The Full Monty.”